# array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, chess

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "common.h"
#include "squares.h"
#include "board.h"
using namespace std;
int Board::board_length=8;
int main()
{
    Board *tabla=new Board();
    tabla->printBoard();
}
```

board.h :

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H
#include "squares.h"

class Board
{
   static int board_length;
   Square boardSquares[board_length][board_length];
   public:
   Board();
   void printBoard();

};
```

error line 8 in board.h
C:\c++ projects\CHESS-P3\board.h|8|error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token|

Comment: You posted the same code twice.

Comment: the error is in code you arent showing.

Comment: The error is in `board.h` which you don't show us. Please always show us a proper [mcve] and copy-paste the full and complete build output. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: As a ***guess***, you use a variable or other non-constant value as the size of an array. In C++ all array sizes must be compile-time constants.

Comment: are you using `int Board::board_length=8;` as size of an array? Thats not a constant.

Comment: You're probably running afoul of the [variable-length array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) issue in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: i edited it, sorry i'm new to formating questions

Comment: By the way, there's no reason to use a pointer in this code snippet: `Board tabla; tabla.printBoard();`—leak gone.

Comment: Yep, the commenters guessed right. You are using variable length array. One thing you can do (if you are not using ancient compiler) is to change `board_length` to `constexpr static int board_length = 8;` (and remove definition from `main.cpp`). This way you will have a compile time constant, which can be used to create an array. https://wandbox.org/permlink/9v8Cn7VyeE1ploEx#

Comment: @chris if i don t use the pointer i have another error: conversion from board* to non-scalar type Board

Comment: @palalele, Don't use `new` if you can avoid it. The code I showed does the same thing but without the memory leak

Comment: @palalele If you look at the suggested code from chris then you will see that it doesn't use `new`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen thanks, it s working now. sorry for my mistake guys

Comment: thanks @chris and the other guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message indicates, `board_length` is not a constant value. To fix that, change the line

```
static int board_length;
```

in `board.h` to

```
static const int board_length = 8;
```

and remove the line

```
int Board::board_length=8;
```

from your main file. This *should* compile, but I cannot tell for sure, since you did not provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

**Bonus:** To avoid a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) you should also change

```
Board *tabla=new Board();
tabla->printBoard();
```

in main just to

```
Board tabla;
tabla.printBoard();
```

Since you do not seem to be passing the `Board` instance around, there is no need to use a pointer here.

As a general rule of thumb: Whenever there is a `new` somewhere, there also needs to be a corresponding `delete`. Otherwise your pogram may leak memory. While this is no big deal for a small, short-running example program, it can become a serious issue for a program that runs for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice use case for an int template:

board.h

```
template<int _board_length>
class Board
{
   static const int board_length = _board_length;
   int boardSquares[_board_length][_board_length];
   public:
   Board(){};
   void printBoard(){};

};
```

main.cpp

```
...
constexpr int BL=8;

//odr declare the static member if it matters
template<>
const int Board<BL>::board_length;


int main() {
    Board<BL> tabla;
    tabla.printBoard();
}
```

That way, the actual dimensions of the array are defined in the main and not in the include file where the class is declared, and all the methods in `Board` can know the actual size.